# Move Second Search Result to First in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

I just updated my Windows to 10 and found that when I search for a software the previous top hit is now on second place. So I have to navigate to select it. The current top is a related software that share the same first word. (I am only entering the first word). Is there a way to make the second result be the first when entering the first word? Removing the current top hit all together from search result is fine with me, but I need it from time to time so I can't uninstall it.