# Organize Search Results in Windows 10 Start Search

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, windows-10-v1607

I'm trying to change the order of results when searching for an application in the Windows 10 Start Search, similar to [this unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/954621/move-second-search-result-to-first-in-windows-10).

For example, when searching for "Code" for Visual Studio Code, I get the following:

[image: Start Bar Search for Code]

My first instinct was to remove the location of code.cmd from indexing, but it doesn't appear to be indexed. `code.cmd` exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin`, which isn't being indexed:

[image: Indexed Locations]

Additionally, I removed the `.cmd` extension from being indexed entirely:

[image: cmd removed from indexed file types]

It appears that the Windows 10 search has nothing to do with indexing now. Is there any way to manipulate the search results so programs I expect to appear at the top do?